# Including files (NOT classpath resource) in Quarkus Native

Tags: quarkus, quarkus-native

In Quarkus, to include random files *as classpath resource*, we use `quarkus.native.resources.includes` (https://quarkus.io/guides/writing-native-applications-tips#including-resources).

How to include files *in the file system*? I.e. something read using `new File(thePath)`.

If we use Jib, we simply put those files inside `src/main/jib`. But that's for non-native.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building a native binary has nothing to do with adding files to the file system of the target platform.

If your goal is to create a container image using the native binary and also add files to the container image's filesystem, then you can use Quarkus with [Jib](https://quarkus.io/guides/container-image#jib) and the files to `src/main/jib` (as you mentioned). These files will be included on the built container image as described [here](https://quarkus.io/guides/container-image#including-extra-files).